# Call C from Android using JNI with only a C shared library and header file

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

```
Android Studio 0.3.1
```

Hello,

I have the following library written in C but don't have the source code for it only the libapp_module.so

```
libapp_module.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

I have the header file for this library:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef _WIN32
#define LIB_API(type) __declspec(dllexport) type
#else 
#define LIB_API(type) type
#endif

LIB_API(int) module_init();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The problem is the exception when I try and call the function from my Android App:

```
D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.sunsystems.snaptest-1/libapp_module.so 0x416f3d88
D/dalvikvm﹕ No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.sunsystems.snaptest-1/libapp_module.so 0x416f3d88, skipping init
W/dalvikvm﹕ No implementation found for native Lcom/sunsystems/snaptest/App_Module;.module_init:()I
UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.sunsystems.snaptest.App_Module.module_init:()I
```

This is what I am doing

I have created a Android App and I want to call that module_init() from my App so I have created a class called App_Module.java

```
public class App_Module {
    /* Load native C libraries */
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("app_module");
    }

    public native static int module_init();
}
```

And I used JNI like this in my root of the project:

```
javah -jni -classpath build/classes/debug -d jni/ com.sunsystems.snaptest.App_Module
```

Which generated the following header interface:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_sunsystems_snaptest_App_Module */

#ifndef _Included_com_sunsystems_snaptest_App_Module
#define _Included_com_sunsystems_snaptest_App_Module
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_sunsystems_snaptest_App_Module
 * Method:    module_init
 * Signature: ()I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_sunsystems_snaptest_App_Module_module_1init
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Then in my Android App I load the library in the above App_Module class and call it like this:

```
App_Module.module_init()
```

So I guess it cannot find symbol inside the libapp_module.so library.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: @joni : I followed you and @Joni. But I receive the error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: module_init`. Can u help me solve problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the native method and make it call the function in your library. For example:

```
#include "header_file_for_your_library.h"

#include "com_sunsystems_snaptest_App_Module.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_sunsystems_snaptest_App_Module_module_1init(JNIEnv *env, jclass klass) {
    return module_init();
}
```

Just about any tutorial on JNI or Android NDK will have further details.

Comment: I followed you and @Joni. But I receive the error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: module_init`. Can u help me solve problem?