# Android native executable link to native shared lib

Tags: android-ndk, shared-libraries, native, executable, dynamic-linking

I compiled two different native so file by using ndkbuid. They are running properly when they are linked android java aplication. Now I want to use them also in my native executable. To achieve this I use following Android.mk so my executable is compiling without any problem:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := some include folders
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += some include folders1
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += some include folders2
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += some include folders3
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += some include folders4
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello_world  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L/Projects/workspace/mylib/libs/armeabi -lmylib
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L/Projects/workspace/mylib1/libs/armeabi -lmylib1
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L/$HOME/out/target/product/evm/system/lib  -lcrypto 
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

my hello.c is:

```
int main ( int argc,char **argv )
{
    int a=foo(); //foo is in libmylib.so;

    return 0;
}
```

I simply copied mylib.so and mylib1.so files to /system/lib folder. . But When I try to run my application by using "./hello_world" at the command line, it crushes at link time. My application pure native code so I dont know if I have to use nativeactivity or another thing.

Also I compiling shared libs by using of following Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /$HOME/include
LOCAL_MODULE    := mylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := some sources
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz #-L$(PATH_TO_FOO) 
APP_CFLAGS := -g
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

please any suggestion.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587603/call-c-from-android-using-jni-with-only-a-c-shared-library-and-header-file